# Generating a dungeon with the given tileset with different sizes

Tags: unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

I have a tileset with some tiles and should to generate a dungeon from it. It should be dungeon with one entrance point, one bossfight (exit point within) with three or four ways that can connect each other or not. Looks like this, with one start point below and the tiles instead of points and routes:

https://apptrigger.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/333/files/2018/01/Slay-The-Spire-gameplay-route.jpg

the problem is tiles not standardized: i have tiles from 3x3 to 9x9 with specified doors (some rooms can be angular, like this:

```
++++++  
++++++  
++++++  
+++===  
+++===  
+++===
```

)

all i can find are algorythms for an abstract dungeon or for standardized tileset, so, please assist me with search a matched algorythm!

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82059/algorithm-for-procedureral-2d-map-with-connected-paths

Comment: You might be able to adapt Wave Function Collapse to do this if you add in additional constraints when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) (for start, various paths, end).
Then you need to map this graph to the tiles.
The tiles are just the graphical representation of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

not really the best answer but if you want random you should take a look a perlin noise, you can get some pretty cool shapes from that. then you can use those shapes to generate your room.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Perlin noise generated rooms are useless for me, so i dont want get random rooms, i want to get random room positions instead and i have no any hallways for them, so i want to position that rooms with a known about their doors.